# Cloning WebService

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, clone

Is there a way to clone WebService object in as3? The ObjectUtil method seems to throw an error.

If not is there a way to cache wsdl and assign it to new WebService object so that constant loading of wsdl can be omitted?

Comment: The real question is: Why do you think you need to close a web service?  It runs contrary to what I think web services are all about.  You can have multiple deployments on servers for scaling, but cloning?  I'd like to hear your reasoning to justify it.

Comment: I'd like to call ws methods specifying different responder objects - have different callbacks. So I need a fresh instance of a ws for each method call. Always creating new ws's and calling loadWSDL seems a bit weird, so I'd like to do that once and create ws clones whenever someone calls a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can acomplish what I need using AsyncToken class. It is the correct solution to my problem. With AsyncToken I can re-use the same WebService object.

It does not address the issue of someone needing to make a clone of WebService class.